# Variable selection in Z3

Tags: z3

Is there any way to find the mapping between variable names (or the name of intermediate variables after transformations) and their representative numbers in `sat_solver.cpp` (`solver::next_var`)  or `smt_case_split_queue.cpp` (`next_case_split(bool_var & next, lbool & phase)`)? I know that it is not straightforward, but can someone give me some hints please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, but potentially a lot of work. The formula undergoes numerous transformations before it reaches the SAT solver. Each of them has their own mapping (if they introduce/remove variables), so getting the mapping that is done last may not get you to where you want to get.

The mapping that you are looking for is most likely [atom2bool_var](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/sat/tactic/atom2bool_var.h), but those Boolean variables are (most likely) introduced in the bit-blaster, which has its own model converter that translates those back to bit-vector variables as demonstrated in [bit_blaster_model_converter.cpp](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/tactic/bv/bit_blaster_model_converter.cpp).